# static std::shared_ptr<T> member; vs std::shared_ptr<T> member;?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, shared-ptr

Right now, I think, I must make an important decision in my program. The task is the following:

I have single `class base` which will be inherited by multiple derived classes. Derived classes must have shared access to same instances of `base` members. Also, I want to access those "shared" `Base`s members from outside: from a 3rd `class Foo`, which contains all derived classes. With my current experience I came up with two solutions:

- first one is using shared pointers. Using `structs`, `int`s and putting everything in constructors for simplicity.

```
struct Base
{
  std::shared_ptr<int> m_1 = nullptr;
  std::shared_ptr<int> m_2 = nullptr;
};

struct Derived_1 : Base
{
  // using Base members and doing other stuff
};

struct Derived_2 : Base
{
  // using Base members and doing other stuff
};

struct Foo
{
  std::shared_ptr<int> m_1 = std::make_shared<int>();
  std::shared_ptr<int> m_2 = std::make_shared<int>();

  Derived_1 _d1;
  Derived_2 _d2;

  Foo()
  {
    _d1.m_1 = this->m_1;
    _d1.m_2 = this->m_2;

    _d2.m_1 = this->m_1;
    _d2.m_2 = this->m_2;
  }
};
```

This I have access to the same `m_1` and `m_2` from `Foo` and also from derived classes.

- second solution involves usage of `static` keyword:

```
struct Base
{
  static std::shared_ptr<int> m_1;
  static std::shared_ptr<int> m_2;
};

// providing definitions for Base::m_1 and Base::m_2 ...

// Derived classes stay the same as in first example.

class Foo
{
  std::shared_ptr<int> m_1;
  std::shared_ptr<int> m_2;

  Foo()
  {
    this->m_1 = Base::m_1;
    this->m_2 = Base::m_2;
  }

};
```

In both cases I achieve same result (do I really?). Are there some advantages for one approach over the other? What are hidden drawbacks for them? What is more common approach and why? I am curious about other approaches. I am using c++17 under VS17.

Comment: Print `sizeof(Base)` in both cases, this might prove illuminating. With the first approach, you waste space by storing copies of the same data in every instance of `Base`.

Comment: It's not clear why you even have `Base` class, it doesn't seem to be of any use. You probably want a singleton to house that shared data.

Comment: Base itself does not much, it only hold those shared members, but the shared members are those who do all the job. It is necessary that derived classes have access to some calculation results from Base members. I agree that singleton can be a solution too.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? If all `Foo`s need to access a common `int` then make it a static member of `Foo`. I already wrote an answer, but still I dont really understand what all this is good for. Maybe [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: btw your title asks for `static T` vs `shared_ptr<T>` but your code is `static shared_ptr<T>` vs `shared_ptr<T>`

Comment: @idclev463035818 It is probably xy. After your answer I just realized, that I am not sure if I ever want to create multiple `Foo`s in a single .cpp. But after you told me that I realized that this actually can be helpful at some point of time. What I am doing is refactoring big code base and trying to come up with better patters. In the same situation "they" (from the big code base) just used raw pointer to set common `Base` member and then ever had only one instance of  `Foo` per project and so per .cpp.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thanks, I will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

> In both cases I achieve same result (do I really?).

Well, no. If you use static member, then the member is not associated with any instance, and there is exactly one shared `Base::m_1` and one `Base::m_2` respectively in the program. With a non-static member, every instance of `Base` have their own `m_1` and `m_2` contained within them.

> Are there some advantages for one approach over the other?

One has the advantage that there is only one member in the program, and the other has the advantage that there is one member for each instance.

> What is more common approach and why?

Non-static members are typically more useful. Static storage is global state, which is problematic and is discouraged.

---

It is unclear why `Foo` has the members `m_1` and `m2`, which appear to point to the same object as members point to. Why not simply use those pointers and get rid of the pointers in `Foo`?

```
struct Foo
{
  Derived_1 _d1{std::make_shared<int>(), std::make_shared<int>()};
  Derived_2 _d2{_d1.m_1,                 _d1.m_2};
};
```

Sharing the bases of the derived objects is also possible which would achieve having only a single copy of the shared pointers per instance of `Foo`. But it is only possible if the derived instances are themselves bases of a single derived class. In such case, the sharing of the base is achieved with virtual inheritance.

```
struct Derived_1 : virtual Base {};
struct Derived_2 : virtual Base {};
struct Derived   : Derived_1, Derived_2 {
    Derived(std::shared_ptr<int> m_1, std::shared_ptr<int> m_2): Base{m_1, m_2} {}
};

struct Foo
{
  Derived _d{std::make_shared<int>(), std::make_shared<int>()};
};
```

Comment: To "Why not use pointer in base": Because as I see this, `Foo` is not meant to inherit from `Base`, it "is not Base", but "it has (from)  Base (derived classes)". Doing `Foo : public Base` together with `static` members inside `Base` will work, but it is not what it meant to be.

Comment: @user12700880 I had misread. I've edited the sentence to match the code in question.

Comment: I have `m_1` and `m_2` inside `Foo` because I want to access them from `Foo`, not only from derived classes. In `static`-case I don't want always to do Base::m_1, so I save a copy inside Foo. In the other case `m_1` and `m_2` are owned by Foo and shared to derived classes, so I also have wanted access.

Comment: Your code snipped does the thing, but then I have access `m_1` inside `Foo` via `_d1.m_1` or `_d2.m_1`

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same. Consider this:

```
int main() {
    Foo f1;
    Foo f2;
    *(f1.m_1) = 5;
    *(f2.m_1) = 42;
    std::cout << *(f1.m_1);
}
```

For the first version without `static` it will output: `5`, because each `Foo` isntance uses its own `Base` subobject. The second variant has some errors:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
struct Base
{
  static std::shared_ptr<int> m_1;
  static std::shared_ptr<int> m_2;
};

// defintions were missing
std::shared_ptr<int> Base::m_1 = std::make_shared<int>();
std::shared_ptr<int> Base::m_2 = std::make_shared<int>();

// Foo didnt inherit from Base and had a private constructor
struct Foo : Base
{
  std::shared_ptr<int> m_1;
  std::shared_ptr<int> m_2;

  Foo()
  {
    this->m_1 = Base::m_1;
    this->m_2 = Base::m_2;
  }
};
```

After fixing that, the above `main` prints `42`, because there is only one `Base::m_1` and only one `Base::m_2`.